# What is the relationship between a,b,c, and d that makes the equation equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the relationship between $a,b,c$ and $d$ that makes
$$
acx + ad + b = cax + cb + d
$$

I don't understand what is being asked, I can't isolate any variable. My only attempt was to eliminate $cax$ on both sides and be left with:

$$
ad + b = cb + d \\
ad - d = cb -b \\
d(a-1) = c(b-1)
$$

Where a $\neq1, b \neq 1, c \neq 0, d\neq0$

But I don't see how that's a relation. Can I just say it's true for any values of $a,b,c,d$ so long as the restrictions are respected?

Comment: The relationship is $d(a-1)=c(b-1)$. That's it, and you are correct.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!